# Переключатели в меню шторки

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation-drawer

Есть меню в шторке, по клику должна сохранять своё состояние позиции. Меню такое

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_3"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_3" />

    <item android:title="@string/category2">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_4"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_4" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_5"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_5" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_6"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_6" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</group>
```

Позиция сохраняется для первых трех итемов и не работает для остальных. Я конечно понимаю, что это и не будет работать. Но как это сделать? Для всех итемов?

Comment: Попробуйте `<group android:checkableBehavior="all">`

Comment: делал, всё также

Comment: Рад был помочь:)

Comment: А как я то рад, за вашу помошь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_1" />
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_2" />
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_3" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/navigation_view_category_2"
           android:title="@string/category2"
           android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_4"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_4" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_5"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_5" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_6"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_folder_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_6" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

В классе:

```
navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
        navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.navigation_item:
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                            menuItem.setChecked(false);
                            ...
                        } else {
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            ... 
                        }
                        break;//и т.д.
```

P.S. Проверил, работает.